# when(scenario) and how does GUID column makes sense when we have already primary key?

Tags: java, database, sql-server-2005

In my legacy web application, here is the structure of customer table in sql server 2005:-

```
custId, custName,custAddress,custGUID
1        scott    mark       B36AF54E-F2B5-4845-9595-AC05K898AE14
```

My question is about the column custGUID which is declared as uniqueIdentifier()which is GUID). I am not getting whats the difference between primary key and uniqueIdentifier and whats the reason to introduce extra column as guid.As per different sites i came to know that uniqueIdentifier is uniques across the whole sqlserver 2005 but primary key is unique is unique in that particular table . But i am not able to think of any scenario  of making any column as GUID/unique across the  sql server. Want to understand
when and how does GUID column makes sense? As all team meamber are new, not able to figure out the mystery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tough one to answer, as there are many reasons to do this, most of them not good at all.

You might be looking at a legacy application, where data was stored across multiple servers. To avoid having data overwritten when the data is was finally merged, a GUID column was introduced.

I've seen this in applications before where, for example, staff had a copy of the program on their laptops, and were working remotely without a reliable internet connection. So, all the invoices etc. are linked to the GUID and not the customer ID, making it possible to later merge all the data into a single database, without running the risk of having things get linked to each other the wrong way.

You are correct in your statements that the unique identifiers should have been enough, but think about what would happen if you had multiple databases running at the same time. You could end up with five customers, each having customer ID 4, for example. If I were to make a guess, I'd say this is why the original designers went this route.

Comment: Hi Elward thanks for good reply. Some questions. As you said it will be useful when data was stored across multiple servers. Do you mean here multiple schemas instead of multiple server. As per my understanding GUID will be unique per sql server(it may containing multiple data store schemas internally). Second question, Once data is merged we will be using GUID instead of customer ID.Right? If yes we should do all the find,update operation on GUID itself instead of ID.

Comment: Hi. Multiple schemas or multiple servers, it doesn't really matter. The scenario I've described was for separate servers that were not linked, like a local copy of the database. The data needed to be merged at the end of the day. You are correct - once merged, you use the GUID instead of the customer ID. In fact, we ended up dropping the customer ID column as it was never used again. That's a choice you will need to make, these days, a little bit of extra disk space is not so important any more.